# Bug in PHP Preg engine: look-around Unicode issue

Tags: php, regex

Why following js code words:

```
"آرد@".replace(/(?=.)/g,'!'); // returns: ""!آ!ر!د""
```

But its php equivalent returns `'!�!�!�!�!�!�'`?

```
preg_replace('/(?=.)/u', '!', 'آرد'); //returns '!�!�!�!�!�!�'
```

This works only in 4.3.5 - 5.0.5, 5.1.1 - 5.1.6 versions.

See: http://3v4l.org/jrV0W

Comment: What does the @ do in the PHP version? Shouldn't it also be "/(?=.)/"?  Genuinely asking as I haven't seen that before.

Comment: `@` is invalid delimiter. Check [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)'s delimiter page.

Comment: @BackinaFlash It's valid!

Comment: Are you sure it gives `null`, because I get [gibberish](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AvQ05k), but definitely not `null`.

Comment: check your encoding in the php file

Comment: @Jack actually it returns `'!�!�!�!�!�!�'`, FirePHP shows this NULL!

Comment: Oh, well .. firephp !== php :)

Comment: @PHPst: that works because `pL` is shorthand for `p{L}`, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing some string now I think there is a bug in PREG engine. First three line output what expected, but 4th line is faulty.

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/./'       , '#', 'آرد')   . PHP_EOL; //✓
echo preg_replace('/./u'      , '#', 'آرد')   . PHP_EOL; //✓
echo preg_replace('/(?=.)/'   , '#', 'آرد')   . PHP_EOL; //✓
echo preg_replace('/(?=.)/u'  , '#', 'آرد')   . PHP_EOL; //✗
echo preg_replace('/(?=\pL)/' , '#', 'آرد')   . PHP_EOL; //?
echo preg_replace('/(?=\pL)/u', '#', 'آرد')   . PHP_EOL; //?
```

Out put:

```
######
###
#�#�#�#�#�#�
#�#�#�#�#�#�
#آ#ر#د
#آ#ر#د
```

Comment: There is no bug, did you actually read my answer? I explain why the line with the dot doesn't work

Comment: @TomSarduy As you see in my example `/./u` works expect when it placed into a look-around.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply add the `/u` modifier, the pattern is supposed to be treated as `utf-8`. The  second example works because:

1. Since PHP 5.1, you can use `\p{L}` that can be translated as: **"is any kind of letter from any language."**
2. In addition to the standard notation, \p{L}, Java, Perl, PCRE and now **PHP** allow you to use the shorthand `\pL`. The shorthand only works with single-letter Unicode properties.

---

**UPDATE:** Why `preg_replace('/(?=.)/u', '!', 'آرد'); //returns '!�!�!�!�!�!�'??`

As @MarkFox says, the reason is because in the context of `preg_replace()` it assumes one byte per character and the characters you're "RegExing" are multibyte. That's why your replace output has double the matches you'd expect, it's matching each byte of each character (which I infer to be two bytes) -

No matter what you do with your document encoding, you will need to use [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) to get this working.

**What about that weird symbol?**

When you see that "weird square symbol with a question mark inside" otherwise known as the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, that is usually an indicator that you have a byte in the range of 80-FF (128-255) and the system is trying to render it in `UTF-8`.

That entire byte-range is invalid for single-byte characters in `UTF-8`, but are all very common in western encodings such as `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: The answer explains why \pL works with preg_replace. The reason the dot '.' metacharacter fails is because in the context of preg_replace it assumes one byte per character and the characters you're RegExing are multibyte. That is why your replace output has double the matches you'd expect, it's matching each byte of each character (which I infer to be two bytes).

Comment: @PHPst: MarkFox is absolutely right, in fact, that will be part of my answer :D

Comment: @PHPst: What's not true? I think all is there

Comment: When `/u` is applied the `.` becomes unicode-compatible. For example: `echo preg_replace('/./', '!', 'آرد'); ` returns '`!!!!!!'` and 
`echo preg_replace('/./u', '!', 'آرد');` returns '`!!!'`